# Using sprite sheets in xcode

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to animate my game using a sprite sheet. How would I go about cutting out each sprite from the sprite sheet and using the sprite in xcode? I'm currently using obj -c. I read somewhere that i need to use a frame work, cocoa2d, in order to do this?

Comment: cocos-2d is an open source gam engine a bit like sprite kit. to cut out each sprite make an SKTexture from the sprite sheet then cut out each frame using [rect:InTexture:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTexture/textureWithRect:inTexture:)

Comment: Take a look at Texture Packer. It's a free app which creates texture atlases, handles animations and does pretty much everything else you need. https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker

Comment: @Okapi, I'm trying to use integration frameworks for this project. I've looked at some of [raywenderlich tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners) but the examples seem to be outdated, for instance the example he mentions uses a myscene rather than a gameviewcontroller, which has different properties. I'm trying to find other examples as well, do you know of any?

Comment: Where the tutorials reference MyScene use GameScene not GameViewController. You can cut out and animate sprite sheets in SpriteKit without using other frameworks, I can provide you with code for this if you need

Comment: @Okapi, Where exactly (in what file in the project) would I put the code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In sprite kit you can cut part of a texture out using `SKTexture(rect: inTexture:)` initializer. This is a helper class which manages an evenly spaced sprite sheet and can cut out a texture at a given row and column. It is used like So

```
let sheet=SpriteSheet(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "spritesheet"), rows: 1, columns: 11, spacing: 1, margin: 1)
let sprite=SKSpriteNode(texture: sheet.textureForColumn(0, row: 0))
```

Here is the full code

```
//
//  SpriteSheet.swift
//

import SpriteKit

class SpriteSheet {
    let texture: SKTexture
    let rows: Int
    let columns: Int
    var margin: CGFloat=0
    var spacing: CGFloat=0
    var frameSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (self.texture.size().width-(self.margin*2+self.spacing*CGFloat(self.columns-1)))/CGFloat(self.columns),
            height: (self.texture.size().height-(self.margin*2+self.spacing*CGFloat(self.rows-1)))/CGFloat(self.rows))
    }

    init(texture: SKTexture, rows: Int, columns: Int, spacing: CGFloat, margin: CGFloat) {
        self.texture=texture
        self.rows=rows
        self.columns=columns
        self.spacing=spacing
        self.margin=margin

    }

    convenience init(texture: SKTexture, rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.init(texture: texture, rows: rows, columns: columns, spacing: 0, margin: 0)
    }

    func textureForColumn(column: Int, row: Int)->SKTexture? {
        if !(0...self.rows ~= row && 0...self.columns ~= column) {
            //location is out of bounds
            return nil
        }

        var textureRect=CGRect(x: self.margin+CGFloat(column)*(self.frameSize.width+self.spacing)-self.spacing,
                               y: self.margin+CGFloat(row)*(self.frameSize.height+self.spacing)-self.spacing,
                               width: self.frameSize.width,
                               height: self.frameSize.height)

        textureRect=CGRect(x: textureRect.origin.x/self.texture.size().width, y: textureRect.origin.y/self.texture.size().height,
            width: textureRect.size.width/self.texture.size().width, height: textureRect.size.height/self.texture.size().height)
        return SKTexture(rect: textureRect, inTexture: self.texture)
    }

}
```

The margin property is the gap between the edge of the image and the sprites. The spacing is the gap between each sprite. The fameSize is the size each sprite will be. This image explains it:

[image: Sprite Sheet Example]

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution with all the code, but this is in Swift :/, the OP is tagged as Objective-C

Comment: Sorry, You should be able to bridge (or convert) this to objective-c though

Comment: @bagelboy Please see my response - a `SpriteSheet.m` class in Objective-C.

Comment: So this doesnt require cocoa 2d or anything, just add this to any normal swift app and you could crop sprite sheets filled with images?!

Answer (score 4):

Since the original question was tagged as Objective-C, here's a rough version of this SpriteSheet class in that language. Hope this is helpful:

```
#import "SpriteSheet.h"

@interface SpriteSheet ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKTexture *texture;
@property (nonatomic)         NSInteger rows;
@property (nonatomic)         NSInteger cols;
@property (nonatomic)         CGFloat   margin;
@property (nonatomic)         CGFloat   spacing;
@property (nonatomic, getter=frameSize)         CGSize    frameSize;
@end


@implementation SpriteSheet

- (instancetype)initWithTextureName:(NSString *)name rows:(NSInteger)rows cols:(NSInteger)cols margin:(CGFloat)margin spacing:(CGFloat)spacing {
  SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:name];
  return [self initWithTexture:texture rows:rows cols:cols margin:margin spacing:spacing];
}

- (instancetype)initWithTexture:(SKTexture *)texture rows:(NSInteger)rows cols:(NSInteger)cols {
  return [self initWithTexture:texture rows:rows cols:cols margin:0 spacing:0];
}

- (instancetype)initWithTexture:(SKTexture *)texture rows:(NSInteger)rows cols:(NSInteger)cols margin:(CGFloat)margin spacing:(CGFloat)spacing {
  if (self == [super init]) {
    _texture = texture;
    _rows = rows;
    _cols = cols;
    _margin = margin;
    _spacing = spacing;
    _frameSize = [self frameSize];

  }
  return self;
}

- (CGSize)frameSize {

  CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake((self.texture.size.width - (self.margin * 2.0 + self.spacing * ((CGFloat)self.cols - 1.0))) / ((CGFloat)self.cols),
                    (self.texture.size.height - ((self.margin * 2.0) + (self.spacing * ((CGFloat)self.rows - 1.0))) / ((CGFloat)self.rows)));

  return newSize;
}

- (SKTexture *)textureForColumn:(NSInteger)column andRow:(NSInteger)row {

  if (column >= (self.cols) || row >= (self.rows)) {
    NSLog(@"Asking for row or col greater than spritesheet");
    return nil;
  }

  CGRect textureRect = CGRectMake(self.margin + (column * self.frameSize.width + self.spacing) - self.spacing,
                                  self.margin + (row * self.frameSize.width + self.spacing) - self.spacing, // note using width here
                                  self.frameSize.width,
                                  self.frameSize.height);

  textureRect = CGRectMake(textureRect.origin.x / self.texture.size.width, textureRect.origin.y / self.texture.size.height, textureRect.size.width / self.texture.size.width, textureRect.size.height/self.texture.size.height);

  return [SKTexture textureWithRect:textureRect inTexture:self.texture];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am adding this into a separate answer, because it contains two important things, that I found:

**First :**

```
var textureRect=CGRect(x: self.margin+CGFloat(column)*(self.frameSize.width+self.spacing)-self.spacing,
                       y: self.margin+CGFloat(row)*(self.frameSize.width+self.spacing)-self.spacing,
                       width: self.frameSize.width,
                       height: self.frameSize.height)
```

This code in Swift and its Objective-C counterpart both have a bug. The `self.frameSize.width` is used for both row and column calculations. The height needs to be used for column.

**Second :**
The coordinate system for `SKTexture` places its (0,0) origin at the bottom left corner of the image, this has to be considered when making your sprites or the code needs to be altered.

For example You can get all the frames of the sprite from top left corner to bottom right corner of the sprite like this:

```
var anim = [SKTexture]()
for row in (0..<self.rows).reversed() {
  for column in 0..<self.columns {
    if let frame = textureForColumn(column: column, row: row) {
        anim.append(frame)
    }
  }
}
```

PS. I don't have the much experience with SpriteKit, so if there are any mistakes in my answer, please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

I did a fix for getting sprites from top to bottom, left to right.

Also added a totalFrames so if you don't have a sprite with all frames, you can set the total frames so the array only contains the sprites, no blank sprites.

```
//
//  SpriteSheet.swift
//

import SpriteKit

class SpriteSheet {
    let texture: SKTexture
    let rows: Int
    let columns: Int
    var margin: CGFloat=0
    var spacing: CGFloat=0
    var frameSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (self.texture.size().width-(self.margin*2+self.spacing*CGFloat(self.columns-1)))/CGFloat(self.columns),
                  height: (self.texture.size().height-(self.margin*2+self.spacing*CGFloat(self.rows-1)))/CGFloat(self.rows))
    }

    init(texture: SKTexture, rows: Int, columns: Int, spacing: CGFloat, margin: CGFloat) {
        self.texture=texture
        self.rows=rows
        self.columns=columns
        self.spacing=spacing
        self.margin=margin

    }

    convenience init(texture: SKTexture, rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.init(texture: texture, rows: rows, columns: columns, spacing: 0, margin: 0)
    }

    func textureForColumn(column: Int, row: Int)->SKTexture? {
        if !(0...self.rows ~= row && 0...self.columns ~= column) {
            return nil
        }
        var textureRect = CGRect(x: self.margin + CGFloat(column) * (self.frameSize.width+self.spacing)-self.spacing, y: self.margin + CGFloat(self.rows - row - 1) * (self.frameSize.height+self.spacing)-self.spacing,
                           width: self.frameSize.width,
                           height: self.frameSize.height)

        textureRect = CGRect(x: textureRect.origin.x/self.texture.size().width, y: textureRect.origin.y/self.texture.size().height,
                       width: textureRect.size.width/self.texture.size().width, height: textureRect.size.height/self.texture.size().height)
        return SKTexture(rect: textureRect, in: self.texture)
    }
}
```

To call, just add the animation like this:

```
fileprivate let framesOpening: [SKTexture] = {
    let totalFrames = 28
    let rows = 6
    let columns = 5
    let sheet = SpriteSheet(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "GETREADY"), rows: rows, columns: columns, spacing: 0, margin: 0)
    var frames = [SKTexture]()
    var count = 0

    for row in (0..<rows) {
        for column in (0..<columns){
            if count < totalFrames {
                if let texture = sheet.textureForColumn(column: column, row: row) {
                    frames.append(texture)
                }
            }
            count+=1
        }
    }
    return frames
}()
```

and call it

```
    let sprite1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: framesOpening.first)
    let openingAnimation: SKAction = SKAction.animate(with: framesOpening, timePerFrame: 0.2, resize: false, restore: true)
    sprite1.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    sprite1.zPosition = 2000
    self.addChild(sprite1)
    sprite1.run(SKAction.repeatForever(openingAnimation))
```