# How to use a sprite sheet in swift and sprite kit?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, sprite-kit, sprite-sheet

Title says it all. How do i use a sprite sheet in swift and sprite kit? I've searched google, stack exchange, and the apple documentation and I can't figure this one out.

Comment: Thanks for the question, I was about to have this question myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In xcode 7, you can use Images.xcassets to create a sprite atlas.

1. Click on Images.xcassets
2. Click on the plus bottom in the bottom left
3. Select "new sprite atlas"
4. Then you can drag and drop all your images into the atlas

If you drag in all three image sizes with the proper suffix (@2x and @3x) it will automatically populate the images for you.

Then to use these assets in code simply write:

```
let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Sprites")
let texture = atlas.textureNamed("ball")
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
```

you can be less specific and just specify a texture:

```
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ball")
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
```

If you're looking to use an already created sprite sheet, check out this answer on SO: [Using sprite sheets in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008107/using-sprite-sheets-in-xcode).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: it looks like a way how to use multiple separate images like a spritesheet but doesn't answer the question - How to use spritesheets?

Comment: Can you be more specific with the information you're asking for @VyachaslavGerchicov? This question answers how to use a spritesheet in swift.  They are referred to as Texture Atlases.

Comment: Example of spritesheet: http://flatredball.com/migrated_media/Cowsheet.png   After your steps it will be imported as a single image. How to import it as a 16 separate images? To split them into separate images in the external editor is not an answer!

Comment: Looks like you might want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008107/using-sprite-sheets-in-xcode, The answer is in swift even though it asks for objective-c.

Comment: Lets say I have an image 2x and 3x, and within that image there are two button images with two states, one for normal and one for pressed. Is there any way to clip from that one image file, like it is possible in HTML!?