# How to extract sprites out from Sprite Sheet in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sktexture

I wanted to extract each of the sprites in the following sprite sheet.
Provided with the key-value of sprite origin points in the sheet.
each sprite into its own SKSpriteNode object
I think through using SKTexture somehow
[image]

```
{
            CACTUS_LARGE: { x: 652, y: 2 },
            CACTUS_SMALL: { x: 446, y: 2 },
            CLOUD: { x: 166, y: 2 },
            HORIZON: { x: 2, y: 104 },
            MOON: { x: 954, y: 2 },
            PTERODACTYL: { x: 260, y: 2 },
            RESTART: { x: 2, y: 2 },
            TEXT_SPRITE: { x: 1294, y: 2 },
            TREX: { x: 1678, y: 2 },
            STAR: { x: 1276, y: 2 }
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28050732/4376309 This post discusses how to extract sprites out of a sprite sheet if they are evenly-spaced. Your sheet is not evenly spaced, but it is quite small. I would manually split them into individual images using any image editing program. Then you can create a new sprite atlas in Xcode, like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32635961/4376309

Comment: since you have the coordinates, you can infer size (I am assuming you have 2 pixel padding) so all you need to do is slap that into 1 SKTexture, then use `SKTexture(rect:CGRect, in:SKTexture)` to extract the SKTextures you want.  If nobody provides an answer for you with this info, then tag me later on tomorrow and I will try to whip up a real answer for you.  I would do it now but it is going to be a lot of work to write up a nice answer for you.

Comment: Can you test it as it did not work for me SKTexture(rect:CGRect, in:SKTexture)